# Purpose of Secondary Key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mongodb, database

What is the purpose of the Secondary key? Say I have a table that logs down all the check-ins (similar to Foursquare), with columns `id, user_id, location_id, post, time`, and there can be millions of rows, many people have stated to use secondary keys to speed up the process.

Why does this work? And should both `user_id` and `location_id` be secondary keys?

*I'm using mySQL btw...*

**Edit:** There will be a page that lists/calculates all the check-ins for a particular user, and another page that lists all the users who has checked-in to a particular location

**mySQL Query**

*Type 1*

```
SELECT location_id FROM checkin WHERE user_id = 1234 

SELECT user_id FROM checkin WHERE location_id = 4321
```

*Type 2*

```
SELECT COUNT(location_id) as num_users FROM checkin

SELECT COUNT(user_id) as num_checkins FROM checkin
```

Comment: Are you sure they said secondary key and not index? [edit: apparently secondary key is another word for index in some circles.]

Comment: if you are using mysql, why you've added php and mongodb tags?

Comment: i think mongodb was used in foursquare, and php users tend to use php/mysql combo

Comment: oops i think it should be secondary index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key (also called index) is for speeding up queries. If you want to see all checkins for a given user, you need a key on user_id field. If you want to see all checking for a given location, you need index on location_id field. You can read more at [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: If I have a user profile page that calculates/list all his checkins, and a page for a particular location that lists all the people who checked in, how should I assign the index/primarykey?

Comment: keep id the primary key. And correct indexes depends on the queries. Show your queries and we can tell you what indexes will be most efficient.

Comment: `SELECT location_id FROM checkin WHERE user_id = 1234` and `SELECT user_id FROM checkin WHERE location_id = 4321` and `SELECT COUNT(location_id) as num_users FROM checkin` and `SELECT COUNT(user_id) as num_checkins FROM checkin`

Comment: index on user_id. index on location_id. The last 2 queries do the same thing, if there is no where clause, but I assume there is ;)

Comment: will there be any performance hit if I index both of them and search by another field like `post`? Also, why not index every column that I may potenetially do a search on? Just wondering

Comment: You can use only the left-most part of the index. This means that if you have index on (user_id, location_id) you can use it for queries, where user_id is included in the where clause, but not for queries, when only location_id is in the where clause. Indexing of every field is not an option, because while index speeds up the respective select query, it makes inserts and updates slower. And it takes disk space as well. So there is no point to created indexes on columns, on which the index won't be used.

Answer (score 1):

I want to comment on your question and your examples.

Let me just suggest strongly to you that since you are using MySQL you make sure that your tables are using the innodb engine type for many reasons you can research on your own.

One important feature of InnoDB is that you have referential integrity.  What does that mean?  In your checkin table, you have a foreign key of `user_id` which is the primary key of the user table.  With referential integrity, MySQL will not let you insert a row with a user_id that doesn't exist in the user table.  Using MyISAM, you can.  That alone should be enough to make you want to use the innodb engine.

To your question about keys/indexes, essentially when a table is defined and a key is declared for a column or some combination of columns, mysql will create an index.

Indexes are essential for performance as a table grows with the insert of rows.

All relational databases and Document databases depend on an implementation of [BTree indexing](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/all-about-indexes-part-2-mysql-index-structure-and-performance).  What Btree's are very good for, is finding an item (or not) using a predictable number of lookups.  So when people talk about the performance of a relational database the essential building block of that is use of btree indexes, which are created via KEY statements or with alter table or create index statements.

To understand why this is, imagine that your user table was simply a text file, with one line per row, perhaps separated by commas.  As you add a row, a new line in the text file gets added at the bottom.

Eventually you get to the point that you have 10,000 lines in the file.

Now you want to find out if you entered a line for one particular person with the last name of Smith.  How can you find that out?

Without any sort of sortation of the file, or a separate index, you have but one option and that is to start at the first line in the file and scan through every line in the table looking for a match.  Even if you found a Smith, that might not be the only 'Smith' in the table, so you have to read the entire file from top to bottom every time you want do do this search.

Obviously as the table grows the performance of searching gets worse and worse.

In relational database parlance, this is known as a "*table scan*".  The database has to start at the first row and scan through reading every row until it gets to the end.

Without indexes, relational databases still work, but they are highly dependent on IO performance.

With a Btree index, the rows you want to find are found in the index first.  The indexes have a pointer directly to the data you want, so the table no longer needs to be scanned, but instead the individual data pages required are read.  This is how a database can maintain adequate performance even when there are millions or 10's or 100's of millions of rows.

To really start to gain insight into how mysql works, you need to get familiar with [EXPLAIN EXTENDED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-extended.html) ... and start looking at the explain plans for queries.  Simple ones like those you've provided will have simple plans that show you how many rows are being examined to get a result and whether or not they are using one or more indexes.

For your summary queries, indexes are not helpful because you are doing a COUNT().  The table will need to be scanned when you have no other criteria constraining the search.

I did notice what looks like a mistake in your summary queries.  Just based on your labels, I would think that these are the right queries to get what you would want given your column alias names.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as num_users FROM checkin

SELECT COUNT(*) as num_checkins FROM checkin
```

This is yet another reason to use InnoDB, which when properly configured has a data cache (innodb buffer pool) similar to other rdbms's like oracle and sql server.  MyISAM doesn't cache data at all, so if you are repeatedly querying the same sorts of queries that might require a lot of IO, MySQL will have to do all that data reading work over and over, whereas with InnoDB, that data could very well be sitting in cache memory and have the result returned without having to go back and read from storage.

**Primary vs Secondary**

There really is no such concept internally.  A Primary key is special because it allows the database to find one single row.  Primary keys must be unique, and to reflect that, the associated Btree index is unique, which simply means that it will not allow you to have 2 keys with the same data to exist in the index.

Whether or not an index is unique is an excellent tool that allows you to maintain the consistency of your database in many other cases.  Let's say you have an 'employee' table with the SS_Number column to store social security #.  It makes sense to have an index on that column if you want the system to support finding an employee by SS number.  Without an index, you will tablescan.  But you also want to have that index be unique, so that once an employee with a SS# is inserted, there is no way the database will let you enter a duplicate employee with the same SS#.

But to demystify this for you, when you declare keys these indexes are just being created for you and used automagically in most cases, when you define the tables.

It's when you aren't dealing with keys (primary or foreign) as in the example of usernames, first, last & last names, ss#'s etc., that you need to also be aware of how to create an index because you are searching (using where clause criteria) on one or more columns that aren't keys.